# Android gradle sync issue

Tags: android, gradle

This app was running perfectly OK without any issue. Suddenly i saw this gradle sync problems.I'm really stuck and need help. What to do now? I've uninstalled and reinstalled android support repository from SDK manager.

```
C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Prokriti\app\build.gradle
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
```

**build.gradle  (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.avtro.prokriti.prokriti"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.survivingwithandroid:weatherlib:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle  (project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i didnt update android studio or gradle. Android support repository is installed.

Comment: try changing all your firebase and gas dependencies to 11.0.4
EDIT: just saw your image screenshot, I know everything was fine before, so you could do an invalidate cache and restart android studio. If it persists, try changing your build tools version to 27.0.1.

Comment: didnt solve....need help

Comment: We are also facing the same issue.
have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: @Toughquestions I am also facing this issue from today morning it was working fine till yesterday night. Have you found any solution ?

Comment: facing the same issue. been only like 2 hours since this started. Any Hope ?

Comment: @Emil Pradeep Try  ans given by usere9060393. This solved my problem

Answer (score 39):

I solve the problem by removing

```
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

And adding

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
```

Comment: Not solve the problem, `Error:(49, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.26.0
`

Comment: Thanks, solved by removing `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'` and change with `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'`

Comment: solved my problem by answer given by @usere9060393. thank u very very much.....but i wanna know why FB sdk caused this and why did it happen? i mean it was working fine.....

Comment: some times it is `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'`.  

change that to `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'`

Comment: Literally spent the whole day trying to solve this, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 9):

You need to change only one line.

Fixed by updating **facebook sdk** version

from
**compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'**
to

**compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'**

Comment: this worked for me as well, how did you know it was FB?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

***'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'*** 
or

***'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'***

above *replace* with below

**'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'**

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

by

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Add `google()` in `buildscript.repositories` and `allprojects.repositories` :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Note that this shortcut is only available since Gradle 4.1! Otherwise you must use:
 // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
maven {
   url 'https://maven.google.com'
}

Answer (score 0):

```
Its work for me
Its work for me
Update Android SDK Build -Tools and SDK platforms
Changed in project build file.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
changed in app build file
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
Disable dependencies inspection.
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For react-native projects: Add maven repo to your project. (Removes react-native-fbsdk error after adding maven repo links).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
       maven {            // Add this block
          url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

        // If something is not found from above maven repo.
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }    // Add this block 
    }
}
```

More Info [here](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/issues/180)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

According to [**`Facebook SDK for Android`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/), You should use

```
 // Facebook Android SDK (everything)
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

for updated case read [**`Changelog and release notes for the Facebook SDK for Android.`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x)

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'
```